# Dos window opens along with Blender application. Is it safe?

Tags: installation

I have recently installed blender. Whenever I try to open the blender, a DOS window opens. It closes when I close the blender application. Is it safe?

Comment: That is the console window, it is normal and expected

Comment: **Yes, it is safe.** It appears to everybody that uses Blender.

Comment: it can be useful to see some system messages, you can use the menu "Toggle Window Fullscreen (Alt-F11)" to hide it . Except on linux, where this is not available (to see those messages you have to start blender from a terminal).

Answer (score 1):

The console window is the main part of Blender. If you are lucky, try closing the dos window before it loads the Blender UI, you will see that Blender automatically closes.